# Automatically Loading .csx in Roslyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, roslyn

Is it possible to tell Visual Studio or Roslyn to execute a specific code script every time I reset the C# Interactive Window from my Project?

For example - I have a form with a Plotter that displays most of the data I am hacking around with.  I would like for the Plot to be automatically loaded, and a variable created for it every time I reset the C# Interactive Window from my Project.  So, it would need to run the following code every time it resets:

```
var form = Utilities.InitForm();
```

I can put this into a .csx file and then invoke the 'load' command in the Interactive Window, but I would like to happen automatically if possible.

Is there any way to do this currently in Roslyn CTP?

Thanks,

Giawa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the InteractiveHost.rsp file under the VS extension directory to get it loaded.

Comment: Hi Kevin - thanks for your answer.  There is no InteractiveHost.rsp file that I can find, but I did locate CSharpInteractive.rsp in Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/Roslyn Interactive Window/1.0.11014.5, which is probably similar to the file you are using.  However, I don't know/understand the syntax of the file.  It currently just has entries such as /r:System, etc.  Editing this file does not seem to cause a change when I reset from project, only when I call reset explicitly using #reset.  Can you give me an example of how I might load a .csx file using this .rsp file?  Thanks

Comment: You should be able to just add a .csx file with no /r: prefix to the end of that file and it will be loaded when the Interactive Window is initialized.